# Unit test compare value return from text() with toEqual()?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

How to compare part of returns value from text() function which present in the unit test. 
For example I have angular application there is element . 
I want to test it thus that element is present and src attr has value "img.jpg".

I have tried do it like this and nothing happens.

*If I have something did wrong. please correct me.*

Hope, I expressed my question correct.

Over there code:

```
<img src="img.jpg"/>

it('must has image', function(){
var img = directiveElem.find('<img src="img.jpg">');
expect(img).toBeDefined();
expect(img.find('src="img.jpg"').text()).toEqual('img.jpg');
})
```